# How to parse strings with newlines from a csv file in tensorflow?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, tensorflow

The official tensorflow tutorial suggests parsing csv files by using a `tf.TextLineReader` to read the file line by line and then using `tf.decode_csv` ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#file_formats)). This does however not work with csv records containing strings with newlines, since this causes a single csv record to be split up by the reader.

What is the best way to parse these types of files?

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can parse such CSV files properly if such strings are quoted correctly:

CSV:

```
a,b,c
1,"text which includes
line
breaks",100
2,another line,200
3,yet another line,300
```

---

```
import pd as pandas

df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\1.csv')
```

result:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   a                                      b    c
0  1  text which includes\r\nline\r\nbreaks  100
1  2                           another line  200
2  3                       yet another line  300
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I currently have something similar working with the python csv library, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this using tensors.

Answer (score 0):

tf.decode_csv expects CSV files in RFC 4180 format and according to [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2), line breaks (CRLF) are indeed supposed to delimit records.

TensorFlow version 1.8 has introduced the API [tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/make_csv_dataset) to Read CSV files into a dataset.
I don't know if it solves your problem, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Section 2.6 in RFC4180 specifies that CRLF are allowed within fields that are enclosed by double quotes, which is the case for my data set. The issue is not with `tf.decode_csv`, but rather with `tf.TextLineReader` only feeding it one line at a time. `tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset` looks like it might be a solution, however. I will test it to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Starting with TensorFlow version 1.9, tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset() supports line breaks in quoted strings.